# How do I import a GnuPG private PGP key into Symantec PGP commandline?

Tags: pgp

I am trying to import a private PGP key into Symantec PGP command line that originated in GnuPGP (1.4.11 AIX) into a Windows system.

When I do a `pgp --import private.asc`, then do a `pgp --list-keys --details` I get an invalid key:

```
C:\Program Files\PGP Corporation\PGP Command Line>pgp --list-keys --details
Key Details: Bank (Joint key) <user@company.com>
     Key ID: 0x4aaaa8 (0x09aaaaaB8)
       Type: RSA (v4) key pair
       Size: 2048
   Validity: Invalid
      Trust: Never (Not axiomatic)
    Created: 2014-02-26
    Expires: 2016-01-17
     Status: Active
     Cipher: AES-256
     Cipher: AES-192
     Cipher: AES-128
     Cipher: CAST5
     Cipher: TripleDES
       Hash: SHA-256
       Hash: SHA-1
       Hash: SHA-384
       Hash: SHA-512
       Hash: Unknown 0x0B
   Compress: ZLIB
   Compress: BZIP2
   Compress: Zip
      Photo: No
  Revocable: Yes
      Token: No
  Keyserver: Absent
    Default: Yes
    Wrapper: No
 Prop Flags: Sign user IDs
 Prop Flags: Sign messages
 Prop Flags: PGP NetShare
 Prop Flags: PGP WDE
 Prop Flags: PGP ZIP
 Prop Flags: PGP Messaging
 Ksrv Flags: No modify
 Feat Flags: Modification detection
  Notations: None
      Usage: Sign user IDs
      Usage: Sign messages

  Subkey ID: 0xFbbbb5 (0x96bbbb75)
       Type: RSA (v4) subkey pair
       Size: 2048
    Created: 2014-02-26
    Expires: 2019-01-17
     Status: Active
  Revocable: Yes
      Token: No
      X.509: No
 Prop Flags: Encrypt communications
 Prop Flags: Encrypt storage
 Prop Flags: PGP NetShare
 Prop Flags: PGP WDE
 Prop Flags: PGP ZIP
 Prop Flags: PGP Messaging
  Notations: None
      Usage: Encrypt communications
      Usage: Encrypt storage
      Usage: PGP NetShare
      Usage: PGP WDE
      Usage: PGP ZIP
      Usage: PGP Messaging

        ADK: None

    Revoker: None

1 key found
```

**Question**

- What is a "Joint Key", and should a PGP private key be "joint"
- Is there any way I can tell if the ASC is expecting "wrapped" syntax?
- How do I import a private key from Aix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this key is successfully imported and you can use it to encrypt data with it.

The "Validity" states do you have any evidence that this key was really created by its owner. It doesn't mean that it cannot be used. Check here for more details: http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/#p17

The "(Joint key)" phrase is part of the key User Id.